# List GCP instances not in MIGs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a gcloud compute command that will list instances not in MIGs from a certain project? I thought this command would work but it still list instances in MIGs.

`gcloud compute instances list --project [SOME_PROJECT] --filter='NOT labels.managed-group' --format='value(name)'`

Answer (score 1):

Could you try running this command?

```
gcloud compute instances list --format="value(name, metadata[].key['created-by'].value)"
```

I found that since MIGs contain [Metadata Keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/getting-info-about-migs#checking_if_a_vm_instance_is_part_of_a_mig), I've tried adding the "created-value" to the format.

Expected output would be, if the instance is part of an MIG, it will sort of return a URI. Whereas if not, it would be empty or has a value of `[None]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Unfortunately this returned undesired results.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the below command should function.

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="NOT metadata.items[].key:'created-by'" --format='value(name)'
```

This command displays the instances that are missing the 'created-by' metadata key.

The instances which are not part of any instance group will not have the "created-by" key, according to the observation made by @Soleign H.

Comment: Thank you so much. This returned the desired results.